# QSystemTrayIcon handle left and right click separately?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.4

I have a class called StatusIcon that extends QSystemTrayIcon. I want to set it up so right click opens the context menu and left click opens a window.

Currently the default behaviour seems to be both left and right click open the context menu.

I need to find a way to block the left click and run my own code instead.

From the documentation it looks like this could be achieved using eventFilter I have setup an eventFilter method on StatusIcon with a qdebug in it. This doesn't get called with a right or left click.

I installed it using a line of code like:

```
this->installEventFilter(this)
```

I'm wondering if its not working as its already overriding the virtual method as I've got QSystemTrayIcon as the super class.

Does anyone know why eventFilter is not being called?

Could anyone think of a way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I have also tried overriding the event method thats inherited from QObject. This doesn't get called. This is the [events system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/eventsandfilters.html) docs. It seems everything i try from here just doesn't work. I can't seem to get anyway capturing these click events on QSystemTrayIcon.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `eventFilter`. For left click:

```
//somewhere in constructor
connect(tray,SIGNAL(activated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)),this,SLOT(showHide(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason)));

//...

void MainWindow::showHide(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason r)
{
    if (r == QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger)
        {
            if (!this->isVisible()) { 
                this->show();
            } else {
                this->hide();
            }
        }
}
```

For menu, just use `setContextMenu()`:

```
QMenu *menu = new QMenu(this);
//for example
menu->addAction(showHideAct);
menu->addAction(optionAct);
menu->addAction(infoAct);
menu->addSeparator();
menu->addAction(quitAct);

tray = new QSystemTrayIcon();
tray->setIcon(QIcon("://data/tray.png"));
tray->setContextMenu(menu);//important method for you
tray->show();
```

Comment: That looks awesome. I have clearly missed a major part of the documentation here. I will try this in an hour or so and let you know how I get on. Thank you.

Comment: I just re read the documentation and realised that this is my problem. I have my context menu attached to the icon and both left and right open it. This doesn't fix it as it doesn't have a way of preventing the context menu from opening on left click, or detecting whether the click was left or right. This triggers on both.

Comment: With the code above you will have a left mouse click function, and a custom context menu on the right mouse click. I've got also the same code and it works fine. Or read [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsystemtrayicon.html#ActivationReason-enum).

Comment: I haven't had time to work on this for a few days now but currently i have got very similar code to this. For me though the problem with this solution is trigger is the activation reason on both left and right click. Then the context menu opens on both left and right click. This obviously issn't right. This is happening on OS X Yosemite and Arch Linux with tint2 and openbox. I am going to try and work on this a little bit tonight. I'm thinking of abandoning the context menu for now and just adding the items i need into the popup window. Not what i planned but it will solve my problem.